# Getting AWS Cloud Trail events using Find-CTEvent with multiple lookup attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-cloudtrail

I need to retrieve CreateImage and CreateSnapshot events from AWS Cloud Trail using `Find-CTEvent` cmdlet.
So I try the following:

```
Find-CTEvent -LookupAttribute @(@{ AttributeKey="EventName"; AttributeValue="CreateSnapshot"},@{ AttributeKey="EventName"; AttributeValue="CreateImage"})
```

And I get events only for the first element in the list.
So, where am I wrong? I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Comment: PIpe results to Format-Table and see if there is any arrays.  Most likely you are getting all the results but not viewing the entire array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4/5/2023, this doesn't work. You can only provide a single LookupAttribute value per the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Find-CTEvent.html)

```
-LookupAttribute <LookupAttribute[]>
Contains a list of lookup attributes. Currently the list can contain only one item.
```